# Plotly.js Heatmap Performance

Tags: javascript, plotly, heatmap, plotly.js

I am using Plotly.js to show a heatmap of electrochemical data. It works really well, however, sometimes the data matrix can be a bit large (3000x4000). I paste the code here if it is of any help, as it is a method of a class you will see many references to "this" to get the array, name strings, etc.
My main problem is that for large data arrays, the heatmap takes a lot to render when I load the data or press a button to replot, for example, after filtering. It usually takes approximately between 1500 - 2000 ms. By looking into Plotly.js issues, I have tried several things which did not work, or made it worse:

1. Use 'heatmapgl' as plot type instead of 'heatmap' when the data goes beyond a million points.
2. Use plotly.react() instead of plotly.newPlot(). It did not change although in the plotly.js reference they claim it is more efficient when replotting in the same division.
3. Remove the axes and ticks.

I have also tried to use a canvas to show the heatmap as an image.. but the fact that I need to cast the array to 0-255 and therefore lose resolution in the range of values is also not great for this particular application.
I was wondering if anyone new any other way to improve the performance of heatmaps in plotly.js or if they know of any other workaround. Thanks in advance!

```
  //Function to plot the main color plot.
  var graph_data = [{
    z:this.current.array,
    x:this.cycling_time.array,
    type:this.plot_type,
    colorscale:this.color_palette,
    colorbar: {len:0.5, xpad:30, title:this.current.name+' ('+this.current.units+')'},
    zsmooth: false
  }];
  
  this.plot_layout = this.plot_settings.plot_layout;
  this.plot_layout.title.text = "<b>"+this.name_of_file+"</b>";

  this.plot_layout.xaxis = {
    title:this.cycling_time.name+' ('+this.cycling_time.units+')'
  };
  this.plot_layout.yaxis = {
    title:'Samples'
  };
  console.time('plot');
  Plotly.newPlot(div, graph_data, this.plot_layout, this.plot_settings.plot_configuration);
  _(div).on('plotly_click', function(data){main_graph_clicked(data)});
  console.timeEnd('plot');
```

Edit

The plot settings and configurations are below. I keep them separated because I use them in several different plots and it saves space to save them in the class.

```
  this.plot_configuration = {
    showEditInChartStudio: true,
    plotlyServerURL: "https://chart-studio.plotly.com",
    displayModeBar: true,
    displaylogo: false,
    responsive: true,
    toImageButtonOptions: {
      format: 'svg',
      filename: 'plot',
      height: 600,
      width: 800,
      scale: 1
    }};
    
    this.plot_layout = {
      autosize: true,
      title: {
        text: '<b> Blank </b>',
        font: {
          size: 20,
          family:'Arial'
        },
        x: 0.05,
        y: 1.2,
        xanchor: 'left',
        yanchor: 'bottom',
      }
    };
```

Comment: OOI what are your `plot_configuration` settings? You could try disabling annotations and also make sure you are using the minified version of plotly.js

Comment: I just added the plot_configuration to the question. I don't have any annotations. Are they enabled by default? And I use the minified version of plotly.js, ''plotly-latest.min.js"